# Rebuild a JSON doc by Looping over the contents?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mongodb

*Am looking to .get an `array` of MongoDB docs, build `var` from the array using `object.foo`, and then reBuild an `array` of the all the foobar, once ranked..*

Have another function that handles some variable calculations for ranking.

**Am trying to reBuild the JSON array, using a for loop to iterate over the elements, but:**

..the array starts with a comma for some odd reason

..looping over the newly built array seems to loop over the characters instead of the values

The console logs this: `[01:10:40.833] ", {title: "Title1", quantity: "2", _id: "530c12c66e6b0de318000001"}, {title: "Title2", quantity: "4", _id: "530c12cc6e6b0de318000002"}, {title: "Title3", quantity: "8", _id: "530c12d16e6b0de318000003"}"`

Then the console logs this: `[01:10:40.833] undefined   213`

MongoDB via .get:

```
function getAll(res) {

    db.collection('demo').find().sort( { value: 1 } ).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        console.log("Got the Docs: " + utils.inspect(docs));

        // each doc looks like: { _id: ObjectID, title: 'string', quantity: int}

        res.json({docs: docs});

    });
}
```

Docs looks like this in the console:

```
[ { _id: 530c12c66e6b0de318000001,
    title: 'Sample1',
    quantity: 2 },
  { action: 'Sample2',
    quantity: 4,
    _id: 530c12cc6e6b0de318000002 },
  { _id: 530c12d16e6b0de318000003,
    action: 'Sample3',
    quantity: 8 } ]
```

Javascript Function to ReBuild the Array:

```
  function reBuild(returnValue)
  {
    console.log(returnValue);

      var docs = returnValue;
      var returnedValue = [];
      var doc;
      for (var i=0, length=docs.length; i < length; i++){
        doc = docs[i];

        if (returnedValue == [])
        {
            returnedValue = returnedValue + '{' + 'title: "' + doc.title + '", quantity: "' + doc.quantity + '", _id: "' + doc._id + '"}';
        }
        else
        {
            returnedValue = returnedValue + ", " + '{' + 'title: "' + doc.title + '", quantity: "' + doc.quantity + '", _id: "' + doc._id + '"}';
        }

      }

    console.log(returnedValue);

      var newDocs = returnedValue;
      var newDoc;
      for (var i=0, length=newDocs.length; i < length; i++){
        newDoc = newDocs[i];

        console.log(newDoc.title);

      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

See you can't simply assign String value to a array type variable. JavaScript allows you do so because it is a loosely typed(or dynamically typed). But it you case it is the cause for your problem.

In your code:

```
function reBuild(returnValue)
  {
      console.log(returnValue);    
      var docs = returnValue;
      //==> Initializes to a array type i.e. equivalent to var returnedValue = new Array();
      var returnedValue = []; 
      var doc;
      for (var i=0, length=docs.length; i < length; i++){
        doc = docs[i];    
        //==>Its better to use === if you want equality without type coersion. i.e. the values must be equal in type as well.
        if (returnedValue == []){     
        //==>Here you are changing the type of `returnedValue` variable from array to String
//So this condition start failing from next loop onwards.
                returnedValue = returnedValue + '{' + 'title: "' + doc.title + '", quantity: "' + doc.quantity + '", _id: "' + doc._id + '"}';
            }
            else{
                returnedValue = returnedValue + ", " + '{' + 'title: "' + doc.title + '", quantity: "' + doc.quantity + '", _id: "' + doc._id + '"}';
            }    
          }    
          console.log(returnedValue);    
          var newDocs = returnedValue;
          var newDoc;
          for (var i=0, length=newDocs.length; i < length; i++){
            newDoc = newDocs[i];    
            console.log(newDoc.title);    
          }    
      }
```

You are changing the type of your variable `returnedValue` in a loop and also you are checking condition `if (returnedValue == [])`. It automatically becomes false since it changes in first iteration from any `array` to `String` type. So the way you can look into is something array function such as `arrayObject.push('YourValue')`

Try the following code:

```
      for (var i=0; i < docs.length; i++){
        //This builds JSON object out of your string and pushes into your array `returnedValue` 
                returnedValue.push(JSON.prarse('{' + 'title: "' + docs[i].title + '", quantity: "' + docs[i].quantity + '", _id: "' + docs[i]._id + '"}'));
          }
```

And the correct operator to typed check is to use `===`. So basically the answer to your question is too broad But I did a attempt to point few of the points which takes you near to solution for your problem.
Happy coding :)

Comment: arrayObject.push() works like a charm.. Thanks for that, really appreciate the insight! Any ideas as to why the next for-loop (the newDocs = returnedValue) returns undefined for each console.log(newDoc.title);.. console.log(returnedValue[i]); before the var newDocs lists everything perfectly

Comment: Might it be because of the absence of commas to separate each doc? With that said, tried the if/else, but returnedValue never === []